# how to slove PlayGamesClientConfiguration unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'PlayGamesClientConfiguration' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
how to solve. i am also using
playgame.basicapi lib but issue

Answer (score 0):

Same error here looks like this class are not in the package anymore

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

The latest Google Play Plug In for Unity doesn't support PlayGamesClientConfiguration anymore.